# RuntimeException : Illegal connection pointer 2382

Tags: android, unit-testing

I googled but cannot find what is meant by this error, can someone help? Thanks!

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal connection pointer 2382.
>   Current pointers for thread Thread[pool-317-thread-1,5,main] [] at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection$Connections.execute(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:606)
>   at
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteConnection.nativeResetStatementAndClearBindings(ShadowSQLiteConnection.java:410)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeResetStatementAndClearBindings(SQLiteConnection.java)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.releasePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:915)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:519)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.**constructor**(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java) at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
>   at com.my.app.db.DBAdapter.getDeviceKioskPolicy(DBAdapter.java:1292)

Comment: post your code also.